# Scope of redirection of std::cout

Tags: c++, redirect, scope, stdout

Hi to all you of you brilliant programmers.
I've been trying to redirect `std::cout` to a file, so that for example when executing the code

```
std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
```

the word "hello" will be written to the file I'm redirecting to.

I have the followig program:

```
// Redirection.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc == 2){
        std::cout << "Output file supplied, redirecting to output.txt" << std::endl;
        std::ofstream out("C:\\Avner\\HUJI\\CPP\\ex2\\output.txt");
        std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
        std::cout << "This file contains output of Redirection.cpp" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "This should be displayed in console or in the output file, if supplied" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting `output.txt` to read:

```
This file contains output of Redirection.cpp
This should be displayed in console or in the output file, if supplied
```

but instead it only reads:

```
This file contains output of Redirection.cpp
```

I figure that the redirection I used applied only to that scope, and not to any outer scope.

How can I fix this? The behaviour I need is such that only if an output file is supplied all printing will be written to that file instead of the console.

Thanks a bunch for the free help love and support!

Comment: No, your `out` object is out of scope..

Comment: Do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Hi pete. I don't think so, but that's what they've asked us in class. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `cout` variable outside the `if`, so that it doesn't go out of scope when the `if` ends.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ofstream out;
    if (argc == 2) {
        std::cout << "Output file supplied, redirecting to output.txt" << std::endl;
        out.open("C:\\Avner\\HUJI\\CPP\\ex2\\output.txt");
        std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
        std::cout << "This file contains output of Redirection.cpp" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "This should be displayed in console or in the output file, if supplied" << std::endl;
    if (out.is_open()) {
        out.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to close `out`. Its destructor will do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc == 2){
        std::cout << "Output file supplied, redirecting to output.txt" << std::endl;
        std::ofstream out("C:\\Avner\\HUJI\\CPP\\ex2\\output.txt");
        std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
        std::cout << "This file contains output of Redirection.cpp" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "This should be displayed in console or in the output file, if supplied" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Recall that `out` is an object of *automatic storage-duration*. Hence, at the "**`}`**" just before your last `std::cout` operation, `out` gets destroyed (consequence being, buffers and file resource being released).

So, to ensure the stream buffer is still valid, keep `out` *alive*. See [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061800/1621391) for one way to do it.